# is that possible to built a simple text editor in java without using JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, textarea, text-editor

I have questions according to my final project in my IT Faculty.. I have to make A simple text editor (like notepad) without using JTextArea (GUI Java), I have to make my own JTextArea..

Idea/Topic= Own Text Editor

Algorithms= doesnt have any idea yet

Data Structure= Rope(Member of Binary Trees)

Requirement= Typing without JTextArea...

Is that possible to make that? Can a panel (or something else like that) has a listener or make a listener to do that?
simply thinking, First step I just want to try for typing on a panel, absolutely algorithms needed but i dont get right algorithms so far.. Is that possible?

My thinking is, for text that im typing is stored to a tree.. Is that Rope(Member of Binary Trees) for my data Structure?

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Why would your professor give you an impossible task as an assignment?  It is possible.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible.

Use as you mentioned `JPanel` attaching `KeyListener` and `MouseListener`.

You need a model (`Document`). For simplest case it could be e.g `StringBuilder` where you can add content and show the `StringBuilder` content.

You need caret position (int field) to indicate where the edit should happen.

You need Font field to keep all the font info to be used in the editor.

Override `paintComponent()` and use `FontMetrics` to measure the text and calculate necessary width/height. For the start I would create a text area without line wrap.

Implement viewToModel/modelToView methods. They should calculate position of caret for given x,y and x,y for given caret position.

Comment: StanislavL

thx for your help.. I'll try with your suggestions.. I think that is quite simple to do..
if i have any problems, i'll ask again...